# If DataGridView cell value bigger than another cell

Tags: c#

Hi i want to compare two cells, both of them with number value.
If Cell1 is bigger than cell2 the color cell to be green.

Here is my code: In Cell Formating in datagridview

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells[3].Value.ToString() >  (row.Cells[4].Value.ToString()))
            {
                row.Cells[3].BackColor = Color.PaleGreen;
            }
```

But i get two errors:In first line  Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string' and in second line System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell' does not contain a definition for 'BackColor' and no extension method 'BackColor' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell' could be found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of those errors are valid. You're casting the cell values to strings, but if you want to compare as numbers then you need to make them numbers. Also the BackColor is in the cell's style property. So your code should look more like this:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    double value1;
    double value2;
    if(!double.TryParse(row.Cells[3].Value.ToString(), out value1) || !double.TryParse(row.Cells[4].Value.ToString(), out value2))
    {
        // throw exception or other handling here for unexcepted values in cells
    }
    else if (value1 >  value2)
    {
        row.Cells[3].Style.BackColor = Color.PaleGreen;
    }
```

Comment: error   Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Comment: I get this error in this line:  else (value1 > value2);

Comment: You shouldn't have a semicolon (;) at the end of that line. If you remove the ; at the end and make it else if, it will work. Updated code example to add the else if

Comment: That line should be: `else if (value1 >  value2)`

Comment: Thank you Man!Work!

Comment: I'm glad you got it fixed!

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the string to int, double, long, decimal, or any other number.

Currently you are trying to compare 2 strings together as if they were numbers.

Using .Value without .ToString() should work if j remember correctly